# How to properly update redux state with a boolean value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a React app with a currency unit switch. I have a function to switch the unit and update redux so that every component that has called the unit will be re-rendered. **The problem is the redux prop (storedCurrencyUnit) is UNDEFINED whenever I updated the value and call the update function to redux.**

**Switch component**

```
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { updateCurrencyUnit } from '../../store/actions';

class FrontHeader extends Component {

    handleCurrencyChange = (e) => {

        const { updateCurrencyUnit, storedCurrencyUnit } = this.props;
        updateCurrencyUnit(e.target.checked)
        console.log("unit", storedCurrencyUnit) // this is UNDEFINED
        this.setState({ aud: e.target.checked }, () => {
            localStorage.setItem("currencyUnit", this.state.aud ? "AUD" : "USD")
        })
    }

    render() {
       return (
          <Switch
            checked={this.state.aud}
            onChange={this.handleCurrencyChange}
            color="secondary"
            name="aud"
            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'currencyUnit' }}
          />
       )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    storedCurrencyUnit: state.storedCurrencyUnit
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        updateCurrencyUnit: updateCurrencyUnit,
    }, dispatch);
}

export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(FrontHeader);
```

**currencyReducer.js**

```
const storedCurrencyUnit = (state = null, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_CURRENCYUNIT':
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default storedCurrencyUnit;
```

**actions.js**

```
export const updateCurrencyUnit = (updatedCurrencyUnit) => {
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_CURRENCYUNIT',
        payload: updatedCurrencyUnit,
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you by any chance set an initial value for `storedCurrencyUnit` within the Redux store? If not it's only logical that the initial value is `undefined`. See: [Redux - Initializing State](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question but you can also remove the `compose` call, since you only supply a single argument. As an example, `compose(a, b, c)(obj)` is the same as `a(b(c(obj)))`, `compose(a)(obj)` is just `a(obj)` so `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FrontHeader)` should work just fine.

Comment: Did you confirm the action is dispatched and no/wrong changes are made to the state with redux devtools, can you add information from devtools in the question? And why are you copying `storedCurrencyUnit` to `this.state.aud`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dispatch the action using dispatcher. only that will maintain the promise and let know the redux store.

```
this.props.dispatch(updateCurrencyUnit("some value"));
```

Comment: No, that is wrong. Op uses [bindActionCreators](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators)